# Could the 6 extra dimensions in superstring theory be a product of two manifolds?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, group-theory, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

Could the 6 extra dimensions in superstring theory be a product of two manifolds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I) I will here only comment on the traditional [superstring theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory) story, say, from the first superstring revolution in the 1980s, and leave it to others to include more recent developments.

II) Traditionally, the $10$-dimensional target space $(M^{10},g^{(10)})$ with a metric $g^{(10)}$ is viewed as a product $$M^{10}~=~M^4 \times K^6$$ with metric $g^{(10)}=g^{(4)}\oplus g^{(6)}$, where $(M^4,g^{(4)})$ is the $4$-dimensional spacetime with a $4$-metric $g^{(4)}$, which we see and observe; and $(K^6,g^{(6)})$ is a compact $6$-dimensional [Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold), whose characteristic length scales are so small that it has avoided experimental detection so far.

Let us mention for later that the biggest [holonomy group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) a $6$-dimensional Riemannian manifold can have, is the $15$-dimensional [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $O(6)$, which is locally isomorphic to $SU(4)$.

III) Let us now reformulate OP's question as follows.

> Could the compact manifold $(K^6,g^{(6)})$ be a product $$K^6~=~K^{6-n}\times L^n$$ with metric $g^{(6)}=g^{(6-n)}\oplus h^{(n)}$ of a $(6\!-\!n)$-dimensional manifold $(K^{6-n},g^{(6-n)})$ and a $n$-dimensional manifold $(L^n,h^{(n)})$, where $n=1,2,3$?

I will argue below that that is *not* possible.

IV) Again, to have avoided experimental detection, the two manifolds $K^{6-n}$ and $L^n$ must both be *compact.* Now, another bit of traditional string wisdom is, that to have unbroken ${\cal N}=1$ supersymmetry in $4$ spacetime dimensions, the holonomy group of $(K^6,g^{(6)})$ must be the $8$-dimensional Lie group $SU(3)$, see e.g., Green, Schwarz and Witten, *Superstring theory,* chap. 15. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4972/2451) Phys.SE question.

Case $n=3$: The maximal holonomy group of a $3$-dimensional Riemannian manifold is the $3$-dimensional Lie group $O(3)$, so $K^6=K^3\times L^3$ can at most have holonomy group $O(3)\times O(3)$, which is $6$-dimensional, and therefore too small to be $SU(3)$. Hence a product manifold $K^6=K^3\times L^3$ is ruled out.

Case $n=2$: A similar argument rules out a product manifold of the form $K^6=K^4\times L^2$, because the corresponding maximal holonomy group $O(4)\times O(2)$ is only $7$-dimensional.

Case $n=1$: Finally, a product manifold of the form $K^6=K^5\times L^1$ is ruled out because $SU(3)$ is not$^1$ a subgroup of $O(5)$.

--

$^1$$SU(3)$ is not a subgroup of $O(5)$. [Maximal subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_subgroup) of $SO(5)$ are isomorphic to the $6$-dimensional Lie group $SO(4)$.

Alternatively: If the Lie algebra $su(3)$ is a subalgebra of $so(5)$, then the complexification $sl(3)=A_2$ must be a subalgebra of $so(5,\mathbb{C})=B_2$, but the [root system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) of $A_2$ does not fit inside the root system of $B_2$. Contradiction.