# Alternatives to Calabi-Yau spaces?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification, calabi-yau

Are there alternatives to Calabi-Yau spaces describing dimensions in superstring theory? If yes, what are they? If no, why?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/199380/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4972/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13945/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24540/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Sten! I know I'm supposed to put this into an expanded answer form but unfortunately my circumstances don't allow me to answer in detail. I hope someone will mention it in their answers or you can look into it. There are other manifolds beyond Calabi-Yau. Most notable are the Spin(7) and $G_2$ manifolds used in the compactifcation of M-theory. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Schroedinger's dog! That is good information. I will look at Spin(7) and G2 manifolds.

Comment: Thank you, Qmechanic, for links to interesting and somewhat clarifying information!